# Life bar doesn't change after players destroy collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to do a 2d game and my object doesn't affect the player's lifebar after they collide. The player's healthbar will will get a bigger lifetime but I think something it's wrong with the scripts. (Also the collider of object that needs to be destroy is "is trigger" checked). I put this PowerUp on the object, and the character script and healthbar script on the player.

**Character.cs**

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float dirX;

    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed = 5f, jumpForce = 600f, bulletSpeed = 500f;

    Vector3 localScale;

    public Transform barrel;
    public Rigidbody2D bullet;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        localScale = transform.localScale;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            Jump();

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            Fire();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        var firedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation);
        firedBullet.AddForce(barrel.up * bulletSpeed);
    }

}
```

**HealthBar.cs**

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public Gradient gradient;
    public Image fill;
    public float health = 100;

    public void SetMaxHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.maxValue = health;
        slider.value = health;

        fill.color = gradient.Evaluate(1f);
    }

    public void SetHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.value = health;

        fill.color = gradient.Evaluate(slider.normalizedValue);
    }

}
```

**PowerUp.cs**

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float multiplayer = 1.4f;
    public GameObject pickupEffect;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
         if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Pickup(other);
        }
    }

    void Pickup(Collider player)
    {
        //Spawn a cool effect
        Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        //Apply effect to the player
        HealthBar stats =player.GetComponent<HealthBar>();
        stats.health *= multiplayer;
        // Remove Effect
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us if the collision is happening first? You are using `OnTriggerEnter` which is NOT the same as `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Change that and pass in a `Collider2D` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as others already mentioned for a **2D** game with [`Rigidbody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) and (hopefully) [`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) components you want to use [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) instead!

The Physics and Physics2D are two completely separated engines and don't know each other. A 3D `OnTriggerEnter` will never get called for 2D physics events like collisions etc.

---

Then note that

> Also the collider of object that needs to be destroy is "is trigger" checked

this is exactly the wrong way round. If your object shall track a `OnTriggerEnter` then the one that enters (**the player**) should have `isTrigger` enabled! In most cases you don't want to do this because the player shall e.g. actually collide with the floor and not fall through it etc.

So what you would need is rather putting an additional script on the player itself that waits for other trigger objects to enter!

Then to be sure either [debug your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) line by line or add additional logs in order to see what happens:

**PowerUp**

```c#
// put this on the pickup item
public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Make these private, nobody else needs access to those
    // (Encapsulation)
    [SerializeField] private float multiplayer = 1.4f;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject pickupEffect;

    public void Pickup(HealthBar stats)
    {
        //Spawn a cool effect
        Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        //Apply effect to the player
        stats.health *= multiplayer;
        // Remove Effect
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**PowerUpDetector** (on the player)

```c#
// put on player!
public class PowerUpDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private HealthBar healthbar;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!healthBar) healthBar = GetComponent<HealthBar>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // or whatever tag your powerups have
        if (!other.CompareTag("PowerUp"))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Registered a collision but with wrong tag: {other.tag}", this);
            return;
        }

        var powerup = other.GetComponent<PowerUp>();
        if(!powerup)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Object {other.name} is tagged PowerUp but has no PowerUp component attached", this); 
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Found powerup, pick it up!", this);
        powerup.Pickup(healthbar);
    }
}
```

---

Well, and then what you do is only changing the `float` value

```c#
stats.health *= multiplayer;
```

but you never update the GUI accordingly like you would do when instead using

```c#
stats.SetHealth(stats.health * multiplayer)
```

(Btw: I think you mean `multiplier` ;) )

---

I would suggest to rather implement a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) like e.g.

```c#
public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Make these private, nobody else needs access to those
    // (Encapsulation)
    [SerializeField] private Slider slider;
    [SerializeField] private Gradient gradient;
    [SerializeField] private Image fill; 
    [SerializeField] private float health = 100;

    public float Health 
    { 
        get { return health; }
        set 
        {
            health = value;
            slider.value = health;
            fill.color = gradient.Evaluate(slider.normalizedValue);
        }
    } 

    // be careful with variable names if you have this name already 
    // for a class field .. was ok this time but might get confusing
    public void SetMaxHealth(int value)
    {
        slider.maxValue = value; 
        // The property handles the rest anyway
        Health = value;
    }
}
```

so now instead of calling `SetHealth` you simply assign a new value to `Health` and its setter is automatically execute as well so your GUI is updated.

```c#
public void Pickup(HealthBar stats)
{
    //Spawn a cool effect
    Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    //Apply effect to the player
    stats.Health *= multiplayer;

    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that for my healthbar I used a slider

Comment: If I want to increase the health just a bit I should put at multiplayer = 0.1f ?

Comment: No ... if you do that everytime you get `Health = Health / 10;` ^^ I actually wouldn't use multiplication at all but rather e.g. `Health += gain;` and set e.g. `float gain = 5;` so everytime you gain a fixed value of `5`

Comment: and if I want to object to get destroyed after my player collides with it what should I add? because everytime it collides it doesn't disappear like eg : catching coins

Comment: I don't understand the last question ... you already have `Destroy(gameObject);` which should destroy the item ... or do you mean the instantiated `pickupEffect` ?

Comment: yeah it didn't destroyed the object

Comment: probably because of the effect

Comment: well I guess it does detrosy the item but not the effect. You could use a delayed destroy like e.g. `var effect = Instantiate(pickUpEffect, transofrm.position, transform.rotation);` and then `Destroy(effect, 3.0f);` in order to destroy the effect after 3 seconds. Alternatively you could have a script on the effect itself that handles the destruction with a timeout

Answer (score 0):

Your qustions are below,

- player will get a bigger lifetime
- Also the collider of object that needs to be destroy

What situation possibly you could have

- 1. Check your Character is Triggered, so it calls 'OnTriggerEnter' and also check tag.
- 2. Check your powerUp item that checked true as trigger, 'isTrigger'
     [image]
- 3. Check if collider or hit object scale is tiny, it won't work with collider.
- 4. If you have nothing with above check-list, then it should be working